# If f is even integrable function on [0,a] prove that f is integrable on [-a,a] and that $\int_{-a}^{0} f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

let f be an even function and suppose that f is integrable on [0,a].prove that f is integrable on [-a,a] and that $\int_{-a}^{0} f(x) dx =  \int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx $

The answer is given below:

[image]

But I have a difficulty understanding the third line in the solution, does it contain a typo i.e. t must be -t in the second equality??

Comment: What is confusing about the third line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the second inequality contains a $t$. This is because $f$ is even, therefore, $f(-t)=f(t)$.

This means that the values $f$ takes on the interval $[x_{k-1}, x_k]$ are the same that $f$ takes on the interval $[-x_k, -x_{k-1}]$.

---

A strict proof of the claim would indeed require multiplying the inequalities, in particular,a more rigorous equality would be written like so:

$$\begin{align}\sup\{f(t)| -x_k \leq t \leq -x_{k-1}\} &= \sup\{f(-t)|-x_k\leq t \leq -x_{k-1}\}\\& = \sup\{f(-t)|x_{k-1}\leq -t \leq x_k\}\\&=\sup\{f(\tau)|x_{k-1}\leq \tau\leq x_k\}\end{align}$$
In line one, I use only the fact that $f$ is odd. In line $2$, I just multiply the inequality by $-1$, and in line $3$, I introduce a new variable $\tau=-t$.

Comment: but we have to multiply the inequality by -1 in the second part

Comment: that is clearer thank you :)

Comment: @hopefully You don't multiply the inequality. You use the fact that for every $t\in[-x_k, -x_{k-1}]$, there exists some $\tau\in[x_{k-1}, x_k]$  such that $f(t)=f(\tau)$.

Comment: @hopefully Technically, you *do* multiply the inequality, but you also introduce $-t$ into the argument of $f$. I updated my answer to show exactly what happens.

Comment: if I want to prove it for odd functions what will be the difference?

Comment: @hopefully Well you won't have $f(t)=f(-t)$ any more. To see what exactly the difference will be, I advise you try to do it, and see for yourself!

Comment: I will get $L = -U$ correct?

Comment: @hopefully That sounds about right, yes

Comment: but to prove the integrability of f on [-a, a] what shallI do?

Comment: @hopefully Please post a new question. The question this post is addressing is clearly answered, and the logical step is to accept the answer and move on. You will also reach more people that way. Currently, I am the only one that knows what you are trying to do.

Comment: it is so easy I managed to do it ..... thank u sooo much for your great help :)

Comment: @hopefully You are welcome. Again, remember, if an answer is what you needed, the next thing to do is accept it.